# How to change this mysql select into sql server select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, select, concatenation

I use this mysql statement for concating description which has a length greater than 30..

```
select if (CHAR_LENGTH(description)>30,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(description,1,30),
'.....'),description) as description from table
```

How to change this mysql select into sql server select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT description = CASE 
    WHEN LEN(description) > 30 THEN SUBSTRING(description, 1, 30) + '...'
    ELSE description 
END
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT LEFT(description,30) as description FROM table

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CASE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx); something like:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(description) > 30 
    THEN SUBSTRING(description,1,30) + '.....'
    ELSE description
    END as description 
FROM 
    table
```